# Only show me the number of remaining reviews I can actually do something about

Tags: feature-request, review

When I go to the review queues, there is one and only one relevant piece of information I need: "how many reviews can I do *right now*?" The other reviews don't concern me, because I won't be able to do anything about them today anyway. Yet the numbers that are displayed to me don't help at all.

I'd like to propose that the total items counter for review queues be replaced with the number of reviews I can actually do something about. In other words, find the minimum between the number of reviews I have left and the number of items there are to review, and display that.

Take Stack Overflow as an example. With this proposal, right now, I would see the following:

[image]

This contains the information I *actually* want: how much can I do right now?

It also has a side benefit of improving peoples' motivation. If you finish 40 close vote tasks, you can come back and the queue says "0" - you made *actual progress*. Right now, the queue says 9.5k, and no matter what I do, it'll still say 9.5k.

**Note:** The information on how many items are left would still be available under the review stats page, so we wouldn't be losing that information:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit thick, but I don't get how this is different at all from how the review page currently looks.  Maybe it's somehow different once you reach 15K rep?  I only have one site where I have even 10K (SciFi) and it already looks pretty much like what you showed in your 'what it would look like' example. Admittedly the queue is empty on SciFi right now, so you might mean the relevant tags - but unless that's what you mean, I don't get it.

Comment: @Zibboz It wouldn't make a difference on most sites. It would only make a difference when the queues aren't empty, like on Stack Overflow, or when you've completed most of your reviews for the day. For comparison, [this is what Stack Overflow looks like right now.](http://prntscr.com/7dkdzf)

Comment: Honestly, I'd just be happy if the number in the review bar at the top of every page cleared to zero when I addressed all of the reviews I can.